# simple regex to matching multiple word with spaces/multiple space or no spaces and special characters

Tags: regex

I have a string that is delimited by a comma.
The first 3 fields are static.
Fields 4-20 are dynamic and can contain any string even if it has special characters but cannot be empty.
Field 21 is static
Field 22 is dynamic and can contain any string even if it has special characters.
Fields 23,24 are static.

I need to make sure the string matches the above criteria and is a match, but am wondering on how to make fields 4-20 have the option of containing the special characters and not be blank. (Total of 17 between 4-20)

If I remove the requirement of the special characters this seems to work:

Field1\,Field2\,Field3\,+([\w\s\,]+)F21/C\,[\w\s\,]+(F/23\,)(Field24)

with this string
Field1,Field2,Field3,F4,f5,6f 1,f72,f8,F9,F10,F1,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,F21/C,F22,F/23,Field24

Is there a way to accomplish this with fields 4-20 having special characters and not being empty like "" or " " or am I pushing it too far?

I know I can parse it through c# but I'm experimenting with Regex and it seems pretty powerful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand the problem
But I think that's what you want bottom line:

```
s1,s2,s3,([^ ,]+,){17}s21,[^ ,]+,s23,s24
```

replace the sX to relevant static fields.

example:
https://regex101.com/r/EaAPKH/1